# Modal Popup Not working when i use it in Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, modalpopup

I am Using Area in .Net Core . And the same code works when it is not in Area.
I believe i am using everything correctly, but is it because i use Area. and it doesnt work in area.
or is it because i have a `@Html.Partial` tag used .  Please help me out .

The Modal Popup doesnt show up in this project. In this project I use Areas. Since it wasn't working with areas, I created a separate project to test it, which doesn't have an Area, and there it worked. So the `AddNewLink` Action is in `LinksController` under the area `Creator`, the Url is going to be Creator/Links/AddNewLink. But it doesnt popup at all when run in an Area.

**Controller :**

```
public IActionResult AddNewLink()
        {
            Links link = new Links();  
            return PartialView("_LinksPartial", link);
        }
```

**
_LinksPartial.cshtml **

```
@model Links

<div class="modal fade" id="addNewLink">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addLinkLabel">Create New Link</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>x</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="AddNewLink">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="linkName">Link Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="linkName" type="text" class="form-control" id="link-name"/>
                        <span asp-validation-for="linkName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="LinkUrl" class="col-form-label">URL</label>
                        <input asp-for="LinkUrl" class="form-control" id="link-url"/>
                        <span asp-validation-for="LinkUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    })

    PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var url = "/Links/" + actionUrl;
        var sendData = form.serialize();
        $.post(url, sendData).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
        })
    })
})
```

Index.Cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Links>
@Html.Partial("_Nav-tabPartial")
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Links";
}
<div>
    <h1>Links</h1>
</div>
<div id="PlaceHolderHere"></div>

@{
    string[] className = { "border-success", "border-danger", "border-info", "border-light", "border-dark" };
    Random RD = new Random();
}

<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="col">
        @if (Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var obj in Model)
            {
                <div class="card text-dark @(className[RD.Next(0,2)]) mb-3" style="max-width: 40rem;          max-height: 10rem">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="text-end col">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#addNewLink" 
                                    data-url="@Url.Action($"EditLink/{obj.id}")"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#addNewLink"
                                    data-url="@Url.Action($"DeleteLink/{obj.id}")"><i class="bi bi-x-lg">
                                </i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-start col-6">
                            <a class="text-start" href=@obj.LinkUrl style="text-decoration:none"> <img src=@obj.ImageUrl width="28" />&nbsp; @obj.linkName</a>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="card-text text-dark" href=@obj.LinkUrl>@obj.LinkUrl</a>
                    </div>
                </div>


            }
        }
        else
        {
            <h3 class="text text-danger">Opps!!! You dont have any links Added</h3>
        }
        <div class="col pt-6 text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal" 
            data-target="#addNewLink" data-url="@Url.Action("AddNewLink")"><img width="48px" src="~/images/icons8-add-link-64.png" alt="" /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this so that it runs when in an area?

Comment: Hi @Akhil pramod, where does your `Index.cshtml` and `_LinksPartial.cshtml` locate in?

Comment: Hi @Akhil pramod, any update here?

Comment: Hi @Rena my Index.cshtml is in Creator/Views/Links/ and it is the same for _LinksPartial.cshtml .

Comment: the folder configuration was already in the correct locations, added the script to the Index.cshtml but still the modal popup is not showing up. but when i am not using areas ... it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here are whole working steps you could follow:

1.Model

```
public class Links
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string LinkUrl { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string linkName { get; set; }
}
```

2.View(`Areas/Creator/Views/Links/Index.cshtml`)

Note: JS code exists in `@section Scripts{}` in the Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Links>
<div id="PlaceHolderHere"></div>
@{
    string[] className = { "border-success", "border-danger", "border-info", "border-light", "border-dark" };
    Random RD = new Random();
}
<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="col">
        //.....
        <div class="col pt-6 text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal"
                    data-target="#addNewLink" data-url="@Url.Action("AddNewLink")">
                <img width="48px" src="~/images/icons8-add-link-64.png" alt="" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
            $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
                var url = $(this).data('url');
                $.get(url).done(function (data) {
                    PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
                    PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
                })
            })

            PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
                var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
                var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
                var url = "/Links/" + actionUrl;
                var sendData = form.serialize();
                $.post(url, sendData).done(function (data) {
                    PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
}
```

3.Partial View locates in

```
/Areas/Creator/Views/Links/_LinksPartial.cshtml  
/Areas/Creator/Views/Shared/_LinksPartial.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_LinksPartial.cshtml
```

If your file does not located in these folders, you need change your returned partial view in controller action with detailed location. For example:

```
return PartialView("/Views/Home/_LinksPartial.cshtml", link);
```

4.Controller

```
[Area("Creator")]
public class LinksController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {   
        //hard coded the model for easy testing....
        var model = new List<Links>()
        {
            new Links(){id=1,ImageUrl="xx",linkName="link1",LinkUrl="xx"},
            new Links(){id=2,ImageUrl="xx",linkName="link2",LinkUrl="xx"},
            new Links(){id=3,ImageUrl="xx",linkName="link3",LinkUrl="xx"}
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    public IActionResult AddNewLink()
    {
        Links link = new Links();
        return PartialView("_LinksPartial", link);
    }
}
```

Sample Location:

[image]